# Build Error in visual Studio in perlio.h and iobuf

Tags: visual-studio, perl, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to compile some project using visual studio 2015 RC but I am facing issues when it tries to compile perlio.c. From what I have read this error is related to Visual Studio 2015 rather than the application that I am trying to build.
I have the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10056.0\ucrt\errno.h(112): note: see previous definition of 'ENOTSOCK'
perlio.c(2896): error C2039: '_file': is not a member of '_iobuf'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10056.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(26): note: see declaration of '_iobuf'

Command errors:
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.22816 for x86
```

So how to solve this error:

```
_file' is not a member of '_iobuf'
```

Comment: It seems like `perlio.c` is using some implementation-dependent details of the `_iobuf` structure (which is an implementation-dependent detail itself). MS has been making significant changes to the runtime recently - it looks like your project is getting bitten by relying on implementation details. You might post information about where the `perlio.c` file is from - the first one I came across has nowhere near 2800 lines.  You might also post some of the code from around line 2896 for context about the error.

Comment: I added some lines missing into the header of visual studio corecrt_wstdio.h from stdio.h from wine. I copied the struct lines where it includes the information about this struct and this thing worked for me. I guess MS VS messed up by splitting some libraries for VS 2015 RC. I hope they clear the issue during the release version.

Answer (score 3):

Just found this while hitting it myself. Presumably you were compiling the official CPAN Perl source. It has many problems while compiling with VS 2015 from its extensive use of the internals of the `FILE` struct. The new CRT that ships with 2015 (the Win 10 Universal CRT) has changed the `FILE` struct to an opaque one, as @Michael Burr mentioned in the comment.

```c
typedef struct _iobuf
{
    void* _Placeholder;
} FILE;
```

- `perlio.c` has multiple cases of trying to use `FILE::_base` and `FILE::_ptr`. These can be disabled by undefining `USE_STDIO_BASE` and `USE_STDIO_PTR` in config.h. (In a clean build `config.h` is generated by copying `config_H.vc`)
- `perlio.c` also uses `FILE::_file`. This one is not controlled by any `#define`. The only way is to remove the offending line.
- `win32.c` extensively uses internals of the `FILE` struct, such as in `fdupopen` where it tries to generate a new `FILE*` from an existing one for the same filename, open mode and file position. There is no POSIX way to do this, and I don't know if there's any WinAPI to do it either.
- `win32.c` also tries to provide a wrapper around `gets()`, which has also been removed. (It was removed from the C and C++ standards for being insecure.)

For the last two points, I have not found any workaround either. For now, you have to either use an older VS to compile Perl, or use 2015 but with an older SDK.

Edit: You can follow the progress on this on [Perl's bug tracker (ID:125714)](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=125714). For better or worse, their workaround seems to be to simply cast the pointer to the new internal struct and access *that* one's internals.